# What do we call this type of argument passing mul(1)(2)(3) how to solve this and how to solve such scenario in case of n arguments passed like this

Tags: javascript, jquery

What do we call this type of argument passing mul(1)(2)(3) how to solve this and how to solve such scenario in case of n arguments passed like this.
I want to understand how this concept works.

Comment: It’s called currying.

Answer (score 7):

It is called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

The main part is to return the same function again and again.

Then you need a mechanism to get the result. In Javascript, the `toString` method is called if the calling function requires a primitive value.

```js
function mul(x) {
    function f(y) {            // the function to return
        x *= y;                // update the value
        return f;              // return the function
    };

    f.toString = function () { // overwrite toString prototype
       return x;               // return value
    };

    return f;                  // return function, enable currying
}

console.log(mul(1)(2)(3));
console.log(mul(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6));
```

Comment: Can you please explain the need and purpose of 'f.toString = function () { // overwrite toString prototype
       return x;               // return value
    };` line

Comment: @Murtuza, every function has a built in `toString` method which is located at `prototype`. to prevent getting a string of the function, it needs a different method for getting only `x`.

Comment: I see that we are setting the `toString` but when does the `toString` gets invoked? I mean It would have made sense if we were doing `f.toString()` somewhere to invoke this function but nowhere we are doing that.

Comment: it is invoked, if a function need a certain format, like a primitive value for a type coercion. some links: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#type_coercion https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive

Answer (score 1):

This is called "[currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)" and is a short hand form for the result of a function call being another function that immediately gets invoked with another parameter.

First:

```
mul(1)
```

Is called and would return a function. Then that function would be called with the second argument:

```
resultingFunctionFromCallingmul(2)
```

Finally, that call would return yet another function that would be called with the final argument:

```
resultingFunctionFromCallingtheFirstResultingFunction(3)
```

Here's an example:

```js
function a(input){
  console.log("function a called with " + input);
  return b;
}

function b(input){
  console.log("function b called with " + input);
  return c;
}

function c(input){
    console.log("function c called with " + input);
}

a("This is")(" a ")(" test.");
```