# Write a Currying with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, currying

In a recent interview, I was asked to write a function that adds numbers and accepts parameters like this:

```
console.log(sum())
console.log(sum()())
console.log(sum(1));
console.log(sum(1)());
console.log(sum(1)(2)()); 
console.log(sum(1, 2)()); 
console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)()); 
console.log(sum(1)(2, 3)()); 
console.log(sum(1)(2, 3)); 
console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)(4)()); 
console.log(sum(1)(2, 3, 4)());
console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, 4)()); 
console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

But I am not able to solve below answer, how to get default as 0 in below output?

```
console.log(sum())
console.log(sum()())
```

Comment: `sum(),()`  I assume you mean `sum()()`

Comment: `console.log(sum(1)); console.log(sum(1)());` I'm not sure this is even possible. How can the result of `sum(1)` be _both_ a returned number, **and** a callable function?

Comment: Yes it's sum()()

Comment: Might be possible by overriding the  .toString method on the function to return the value when it's passed to console.log (as per example linked by Nina below)

Comment: @Cerbrus, it is possible, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44347757/what-do-we-call-this-type-of-argument-passing-mul123-how-to-solve-this-and/44347813#44347813)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832891/variadic-curried-sum-function @Cerbrus here is the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well solution should be something like this:

```js
const sum = (...args) => {
  const reducer = (acc, arg) => acc + arg;
  let total = args.reduce(reducer, 0)
  const add = (...args2) => {
    if (args2.length) {
      total = args2.reduce(reducer, total)
      return add
    }
    return total
  }

  add.toString = () => total;
  add.valueOf = () => total;

  return add
}



console.log(sum())
console.log(sum()())
console.log(sum(1));
console.log(sum(1)());
console.log(sum(1)(2)()); 
console.log(sum(1, 2)()); 
console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)()); 
console.log(sum(1)(2, 3)()); 
console.log(sum(1)(2, 3)); 
console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)(4)()); 
console.log(sum(1)(2, 3, 4)());
console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, 4)()); 
console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

It seems that I cannot quiet find a function that needs to be overriden in order to get nice output.

So in case of `console.log(sum())` you will get `ƒ add()`. But if you write like this `console.log("" + sum())` you will get `0` in console. `console.log` is not calling `toString` automatically :( probably some other method needs to be overriden additionally.

Comment: In snippet everything will work correctly, in my browser console I had a problem with `toString`

Comment: unclear why your add function is returning total. It should be returning `add`

Comment: Well when you call sum(1)(). add function is called without any params, so I need to handle that case. In that case, function needs to return current result from previous function call sum(1). I store that in total and in that case function is returning that result. If we don't do that sum(1)() will return undefined.

Comment: It will not return undefined if you return add. The toString and valueOf would pick it up.

Comment: Yes you are right, I could have return `add` and let `toString` method to cover use case. That would make function simpler. You are right :)

Answer (score 0):

Using toString ad valueOf to get the result out. Using curried function with spread to get the passed in values as an array. Using reduce to do the addition.

```js
function sum(...args){
    let v = 0;
    const f = (...args) => {
      v = args.reduce((x,n) => x + n, v);
      return f;
    };
    f.valueOf = f.toString = () => v;
    return f.apply(f, args);
}

console.log(sum())
console.log(sum()())
console.log(sum(1));
console.log(sum(1)());
console.log(sum(1)(2)()); 
console.log(sum(1, 2)()); 
console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)()); 
console.log(sum(1)(2, 3)()); 
console.log(sum(1)(2, 3)); 
console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)(4)()); 
console.log(sum(1)(2, 3, 4)());
console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, 4)()); 
console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

Comment: hi @epascarello, thank you so much for the reply with explanation, but a little doubt, if I run this code in vscode or also in online console like (stackblitz, condensandbox, stackblitz etc...) then getting ```f sum(...args){}``` and if I run your code then it is working properly. means why its not getting the exact result in vscode, which I am getting here

Comment: Means the console line is not calling toString or toValue. Could be forced to do it with a character like `console.log(+sum(1)(2)()); `

Answer (score -1):

does this helps!

```
function curry(f) {
  return function(a) {
    return function(b) {
        /*return function(c) {
                return function(d) {
            return f(a, b, c, d);
        }       
      }*/      
      return f(a, b);
    };
  };
}

// usage
function sum(a, b /*, c, d*/) {
    if(a && b /*&& c && d*/) {
    return a + b; // + c + d;
  } else {
  return 0;
  }
  
}

const curriedSum = curry(sum);

document.write( curriedSum()() );
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, This will help only in  ```sum()()```  condition not on all output. Thanks for the solution.